# Struct array taking up too much memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

I'm working on a simple game that uses a 2D struct array to store map tile properties.

The struct is defined as so:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        //PRE-GENERATED PROPERTIES

            //Tile Type
            int TypeB;
            int TypeF;
            int TypeW;

            //Tile Roughness
            int RougB;
            int RougF;
            int RougW;

        //GENERATED PROPERTES

            //Boundary Type
            int BounB;
            int BounF;
            int BounW;
            //Boundary Rotation
            int BounRotB;
            int BounRotF;
            int BounRotW;
            //Boundary Flip
            int BounFlpB;
            int BounFlpF;
            int BounFlpW;

            //Movement Properties
            int Movement;
            int Movement_Speed;

        //RANDOMIZED PROPERTIES

            //Randomized Texture Fill
            int RandB;
            int RandF;
            int RandW;
            //Randomized Texture Rotation
            int RandRotB;
            int RandRotF;
            int RandRotW;
            //Randomized Texture Flip
            int RandFlpB;
            int RandFlpF;
            int RandFlpW;

            //Perlin (Temp)
            double PerlinSum;

    } MapData;

MapData **MapTile;
```

And the array is created and run with the following function:

```
//Create Map Matrix
void CreateMapMatrix(MapData ***Map, int xSize, int ySize)
{
    //Variables
    int i;

    //Allocate Map Memory
    *Map = calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapData));

    for(i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
        (*Map)[i] = calloc(ySize, sizeof(MapData));
    }
```

}

```
int = xMap = 2000, yMap = 2000;

CreateMapMatrix(&MapTile,xMap,yMap);
```

My problem is that the memory used during and after this function has run is extremely high compared to what I would expect (I assume it is the memory associated with the array).

Assuming each struct takes up 68 bytes (I know it would be a bit more than this) I would expect the following memory values for the corresponding array sizes. I've put alongside the actual memory allocation observed:

1. 500x500   - 15.5 Mb Expected - 26.8 Mb Actual
2. 1000x1000 - 62 Mb Expected - 124 Mb Actual
3. 2000x2000 - 288 Mb Expected - 435.8 Mb Actual

The observed memory allocation was found by checking the program's memory usage just before and after the above function.

So I guess my question is whether this difference in memory is expected, or whether I've messed up somewhere along the line.

As usual, any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using `sizeof(MapData)` twice in the alloc, one should prob. be the size of a pointer.

Comment: There is no "array of `struct`" in your code. You just have an "array of pointers" which requires more memory and uses more complicated operations to access each `struct`. Also being a 3-star programmer is **not** a compliement in C! I always wonder why beginners are afraid of returning a value from a function, but pass pointers instead.

Comment: Thanks both, I changed the first calloc to sizeof(int), everything still running ok, and it shaved off a few Mb! Thanks for helping me understand the pointers bit, I can understand why so much extra memory is needed now. Cheers!

Comment: `calloc(sizeof(int))` is definitely wrong as it assumes a pointer is the same size as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*Map = calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapData));
```

should be:

```
*Map = calloc(xSize, sizeof(MapData *));
```

You allocated too much memory.